# Weak Linking - check if a class exists and use that class

Tags: ios, backwards-compatibility, weak-linking

I'm trying to create a universal iPhone app, but it uses a class defined only in a newer version of the SDK. The framework exists on older systems, but a class defined in the framework doesn't.

I know I want to use some kind of weak linking, but any documentation I can find talks about runtime checks for function existence - how do I check that a class exists?

Comment: What's the class? Maybe there are other workarounds.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

### TLDR

**Current:**

- **Swift**: `if #available(iOS 9, *)`
- **Obj-C, iOS**: `if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))`
- **Obj-C, OS X**: `if (NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController"))`

**Legacy:**

- **Swift (versions prior to 2.0)**: `if objc_getClass("UIAlertController")`
- **Obj-C, iOS (versions prior to 4.2)**: `if (NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController"))`
- **Obj-C, iOS (versions prior to 11.0)**: `if ([UIAlertController class])`

---

### Swift 2+

Although historically it's been recommended to check for capabilities (or class existence) rather than specific OS versions, this doesn't work well in Swift 2.0 because of the introduction of [availability checking](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking).

Use this way instead:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // You can use UIStackView here with no errors
    let stackView = UIStackView(...)
} else {
    // Attempting to use UIStackView here will cause a compiler error
    let tableView = UITableView(...)
}
```

**Note:** If you instead attempt to use `objc_getClass()`, you will get the following error:

> ⛔️ 'UIAlertController' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer.

---

### Previous versions of Swift

```
if objc_getClass("UIAlertController") != nil {
    let alert = UIAlertController(...)
} else {
    let alert = UIAlertView(...)
}
```

Note that `objc_getClass()` [is more reliable than `NSClassFromString()` or `objc_lookUpClass()`](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/257521).

---

### Objective-C, iOS 4.2+

```
if ([SomeClass class]) {
    // class exists
    SomeClass *instance = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
} else {
    // class doesn't exist
}
```

See [code007's answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068079/35690).

---

### OS X or previous versions of iOS

```
Class klass = NSClassFromString(@"SomeClass");
if (klass) {
    // class exists
    id instance = [[klass alloc] init];
} else {
    // class doesn't exist
}
```

Use [`NSClassFromString()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString). If it returns `nil`, the class doesn't exist, otherwise it will return the class object which can be used.

This is the recommended way according to Apple in [this document](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf):

> [...] Your code would test for the
>   existence of [a] class using
>   `NSClassFromString()` which  will return
>   a valid class object if [the] class 
>   exists or nil if it doesnʼt. If the
>   class does exist, your code can use it
>   [...]

Comment: Thanks. Just to complete the answer for others, once you have detected the class you create it using the `Class` instance returned by `NSClassFromString` (assign it to `id`) and invoke selectors on that instance.

Comment: Notably, this is the _only_ way on OSX, but not the "best" way on iOS (4.2+), though it will work. See code007's answer for iOS specifically.

Comment: What if my class is not a real class but rather a C struct?

Comment: Swift 4.1 is coming with new check `canImport`. [Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0075-import-test.md)

Answer (score 69):

For new projects that uses a base SDK of iOS 4.2 or later, there is this new recommended approach which is to use the NSObject class method to check the availability of weakly linked classes at run time. i.e.

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController class]) {
    // Create an instance of the class and use it.
} else {
    // Alternate code path to follow when the
    // class is not available.
}
```

source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3

This mechanism uses the NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE macro, which is available for **most** framework in iOS (note there may be some framework that do not yet support the NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE - check the iOS release note for this). Extra setting configuration may also be needed that can be read in the Apple's documentation link provided above, however, the advantage of this method is that you get static type checking.

Comment: A little late to the game, but I just ran into this issue when trying to build code that contained `UIAlertController` while still supporting iOS 7. code007's answer is correct, but the extra configuration needed is to weakly link (set from `Required` to `Optional`) UIKit in your project (for this situation, at least).