# Can I use the Core Motion framework on pre iOS 4 devices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, backwards-compatibility, core-motion

I know that the framework was introduced in iOS 4 with the gyro. But is Core Motion backward-compatible? Or I am restricted to use UIAcceleration?

Does this imply that either I can't use the gyro or can't support earlier devices?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The gyro didn't exist on earlier devices, so how could you support it?

Comment: @NSResponder, the conflict is that if the app uses the gyro, it must use Core Motion, but that means the app doesn't support devices below iOS 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Core Motion framework is not available on pre 4.0 devices so you should wrap all related code into a runtime check to see if the [class exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057325/osx-weak-linking-check-if-a-class-exists-and-use-that-class) which is the recommended way according to Apple.

Comment: Is there a 3rd-party library that helps me with this? I think at least there must be plenty of developers who have the same problem: no gyro or no backwards-compatibility.

Comment: Most iOS devs are moving past iOS 3.x  There is something like 2 or 3 percent of users who have not upgraded to at least iOS 4, and those users are probably moms, not gamers.