# Is it safe to conditionally code for iOS 6 and 7 by calling +class?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7

For example there is a new class in iOS 7 that does not exist in iOS 6. I want to use this new class. My app must stay compatible with iOS 6. So I read in some places that you can now do this:

```
if ([NSURLSessionConfiguration class]) {
    // only in iOS 7        
} else {
    // do it iOS6 way
}
```

Is this safe to do in any iOS 6 version or should we still use `NSClassFromString`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weak Linking - check if a class exists and use that class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057325/weak-linking-check-if-a-class-exists-and-use-that-class)

Comment: Duplicate but I like this question more. It's more succinct and there's actually code in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## YES, this is safe.

[This is the correct and recommended way](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3) of checking to see if certain classes are available to be used.