# Objective-C Check if Structs is defined

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, weak-linking

My iOS application can use an optional external 3rd party library.

I thought of using this answer ([Weak Linking - check if a class exists and use that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057325/weak-linking-check-if-a-class-exists-and-use-that-class)) and detect if the class exists before executing code specific to this library.

However, I found out that this external library is not written as Objective-C classes, but rather as C STRUTS and functions.

Is there a similar technique that would allow me to check if a C Strut or function exists? Or some better alternative to see if this library is present at runtime?

Comment: What is the external 3rd party library? They might have some `#define`s you can use to check.

Comment: I can't say what the library is, but you are correct their public header file uses #define, so I'll try that

Comment: See my related question now, as I give more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103121/detect-and-use-optional-external-c-library-at-runtime-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

`struct`s are compile-time artifacts. They tell the compiler how to lay out a region of memory. Once that is done, `struct`s become unnecessary. Unlike Objective-C classes which have metadata, `structs` have no runtime presence. That is why it is not possible to detect them at runtime.

You can check if a dynamic library is present by calling [`dlopen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dlopen), and passing its path:

```
void *hdl = dlopen(path_to_dl, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
if (hdl == NULL) {
    // The library failed to load
    char *err = dlerror(); // Get the error message
} else {
    dlclose(hdl);
}
```

If `dlopen` returns `NULL`, the library cannot be loaded. You can get additional info by calling [`dlerror`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dlerror). You need to call [`dlclose`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dlclose) after you are done.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a classical C function has to exist. It is statically bound during the linking process and it is not, like Objective-C mehtods, dynamically bound on runtime.

So when the code compiles AND links without errors or warnings, then you should be fine.

The same for structs.