# Xcode-beta and updated/new frameworks

Tags: xcode, macos

I run Xcode-beta 7 on 10.10.3. It has new GameplayKit framework and updated SceneKit framework. Can I use them (or their new features) in my current project, or I must have 10.11 beta?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: @HAS I did and failed. I asked question to know if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code on OS X 10.10.3 using Xcode 7β. You can even compile and export the app since Xcode can build it against the included 10.11 SDKs.

You can *not*, however, **run** the app on your Mac under 10.10.3. For the app to run you need to update to 10.11β.

Make sure to

1. always use *the same* beta version for Xcode and OS X
2. always use the latest beta

---

If you try to run an app that links against an SDK that is not available your app will crash before it even started with an error similar to

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal

That is because the app is configured to tell dyld to search in the **system's** `Frameworks` directory for the framework and that directory does not contain the framework on your version of OS X.

---

For unknown symbols in existing (updated) frameworks there are two options depending on the language:

Swift: With Swift 2.0 the compiler automatically warns you that the API you want to use is not available and makes you guard that statement like so:

```
if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {
    let nameComponents = NSPersonNameComponents()
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Objc: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057337/1489885).

Comment: Thank you very much for broad answer.