# __has_include check a class exists against swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In objective-c, I have something like:

```
#if __has_include(<MyFramework/SomeFeature.h>)
SomeFeature *h = [SomeFeature new]
#else
OtherFeature *h = [OtherFeature new]
#endif
```

How can we check if a class exists in swift? This link has some answer [Weak Linking - check if a class exists and use that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057325/weak-linking-check-if-a-class-exists-and-use-that-class)

The good thing about `__has_include` is that it is a compile time check, but it only works for objective-c header. Do we have anything works for swift? Or maybe what I am doing is not a good approach?

For example, I have a class `Machine` and it has a method `Gun`, if I have included a `Pistol` framework, it will return `Pistol`. If I have included both `Pistol` and `AK47`, it will return `AK47`, cause it has more bullets.

Comment: Swift 4.1 is coming with new check `canImport`. [Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0075-import-test.md)

Answer (score 6):

You can use **#if canImport(ModuleName)** in Swift 4.

```
    #if canImport(UIkit)
       import UIKit
    #elseif canImport(MyBus)
       import MyBus
    #else
      // Workaround/text, whatever
    #endif
```

Comment: Note that this only works with Modules. It won't work for example to check if an optional cocoapods subspec is available or if a specific class can be used. Which means that it isn't really an option for features unless they are packed as a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

Compile time checks are still available in Swift, but they are much less robust. In order to achieve the compile time checking, you'll need to define a [compilation condition](https://medium.com/@derrickho_28266/super-preprocessor-directives-with-xcode-8-77bf4d4e5a0c) and setup some new [build configurations](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/using_xcode_targets.html) which can have the conditions enabled or disabled. Swift doesn't have a preprocessor (yet?), so this is the extent of your ability.