# Handling a third party library in iOS as optional/-weak_framework

Tags: ios, objective-c-runtime, ios-frameworks

we develop a framework to provide a particular service with the help of a third-party framework. (added as a sub-framework).

is it possible to handle the third-party framework optional and if that framework is added in the ios app instead of in my framework, will it be found in my framework runtime?

I tried with -weak_framework but run into a compiler error on #import.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514834/has-include-check-a-class-exists-against-swift, both oc and swift has solution, use __has_include directive in OC.