# Firebase iOS build error when checking for framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

I'm working on an app that optionally requires Firebase to provide some additional functionality & thus, if it is linked to the project it should run some code.
This is what I've tried at the top of the ViewController:

```
#if defined(__has_include)
    #if __has_include(<FirebaseCore/FIROptions.h>) && __has_include(<FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h>)

        #include <FirebaseCore/FIROptions.h>
        #include <FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h>

        #ifndef FIREBASE_ENABLED
            #define FIREBASE_ENABLED
        #endif
    #endif
#endif
```

And then in the ViewControllers `viewDidLoad()`

```
#ifdef FIREBASE_ENABLED
    NSLog(@"*** FIREBASE ENABLED ***");
    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithGoogleAppID:@"xxxx" bundleID:nil GCMSenderID:@"xxxx" APIKey:nil clientID:nil trackingID:nil androidClientID:nil databaseURL:@"https://xxxx.firebaseio.com" storageBucket:nil deepLinkURLScheme:nil];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
#else
    NSLog(@"*** FIREBASE DISABLED ***");
#endif
```

Note that the code shows as highlighted in Xcode and clicking on any method takes to its header (even though the frameworks are unlinked):
[image]
I've added the frameworks to the project but I've unchecked the Target membership to test whether the code compiles properly should the required frameworks not be included. Below is a snapshot of the frameworks; required plus dependent as per Firebase's guidelines (all unlinked to the target):
[image]

However, when I build the project, I get build errors as follows:
[image]

What am I doing wrong OR what is the right way to check for an external frameworks existence and conditionally run code based on it?

Appreciate any advice to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the Build Phases tab

Comment: Hi @PaulBeusterien, I'm not sure how that will help as the objective is to get the code to compile even if the project is not linked with Firebase' frameworks.

Comment: To make sure the Firebase frameworks show up in the "Link Binary with Libraries Phase"

Comment: @PaulBeusterien the intention is that the code should compile without linking any firebase frameworks in Build Phase tab

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057325/weak-linking-check-if-a-class-exists-and-use-that-class/10068079#10068079

Comment: @PaulBeusterien this seems to be for system frameworks :(

Comment: It shouldn't matter that they're system frameworks since that answer describes using the Objective C language feature reflection.